# PHP image Streaming in Joomla with MVC

Tags: php, image, model-view-controller, joomla, stream

Hello I have a problem that has me a bit stumped!

I'm attempting to implement image streaming inside a joomla component. 
The Image folder is shared by a number of sites on the server outside the Virtual Host so cannot be accessed from the site directly.

I have tried the following which works:

testfile.php

```
<img src="testImgGen.php" />
```

testImgGen.php

```
?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("c:xampp/htdocs/docs/images/282/Img1.png");
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
exit; 
?>
```

This works fine

so Attempting to Implement inside Joomla component:
src link inside view :

```
"<img src='?option=com_cat&view=item&task=prevIMG&tmpl=Component&fid=282&file=Img1.png' />"
```

inside the controller:

```
function prevIMG(){
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'models'.DS.'details.php');
$model=new CatModelCat_details ;
$model->prevImg();
}
```

Inside the Model:

```
function prevImg(){
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->setMimeEncoding('image/png');
    $img = "C:xampp/htdocs/docs/images/".$_GET[fid]."/".$_GET[file];
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($img);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
        }
```

and this is returning ... nothing 
I have tried readfile()/get_contents_fromfile()
I've Created Blank Templates that pass through no headers and have used "header('Content-Type: image/png');" 
I'm starting to get to the bash head against desk stage!
if anyone has any advise/if I'd be great full to hear it!

I have occasional had the image output as a string! or I get  "interpreted as doc with mime type image" or "interpreted as image with mime type test/html"

Cheers

Kiran

Comment: try just goto url `index.php?option=com_cat&view=item&task=prevIMG&tmpl=Component&fid=282&file=Img1.png` and tell what the answer

Comment: Is there any reason you need it inside the joomla framework? I mean, of course you need to secure it, but it won't be more secure just by using joomla!-index.php.

Comment: To see what I mean by "securing": what would happen if someone types: `?fid=../../../../My Images&file=photo.jpg`?

Comment: Subdigger: direct to URL :- there is Either a blank image page or outputs image as string "�PNG  IHDR��M$mo IDATx���w|\յ���}�"...etc

Comment: giraff: I think I get what you are saying... If i put the whole thing in a new file in the Template i.e. tmpl=image and run it from there?

Comment: giraff: my only concern with that is that it would involve template modifications in every template used. the component couldn't then be directly "plugged in" to a site I would have to remember to add template files too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "raw" parameter for the component request. A quick google search found this tutorial. http://blog.joomlatools.eu/2008/01/joomla-15-generating-raw-ouput.html

Comment: I have tried &no_html=1 and &format=raw I also tried creating a view.raw.php in the View Still nothing ... I can get it to output the stream as text but not as an image! very frustrating

Comment: Can you try var_dump(headers_sent()) before imagepng. If true, then search your error logs for where output begins. Alternatively, run while (@ob_end_clean()){}

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure there is no error in code. In case there is error, and php-error-reporting is on then PHP might be prefixing error text to your png output. In such a case browser assume it as text file rather then image file.